# how to monitor/listen oracle table for any insert/updates using Oracle AQ and java

Tags: java, oracle-aq

I need to monitor one table in my Oracle database for any insert/updates using Oracle Advanced Queue and Java.

Note: The table usually gets 10000 inserts/updates per minute in production env.

Can anyone please help me in this.
Awaiting for your responses.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with triggers ?

Comment: If you want to listen and consume the messages as soon one is produced, then use AQ-JMS Message Listener.